# how too solve this very hard ODE ?!

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$4y^3+7 x \sin(x)+4x^4-(16 \cos(y(x)) -7x-(7/4) y(x)^2) y(x)'=\sinh(y(x))-e^{y(x)-x}$$

I have a very difficult question about differential equations! And I think it has a strange integral factor! Does anyone have an idea about the solution? I couldn't even find the integral factor. I also got help from Maple, but he didn't answer either! What do you think is a way to solve this difficult question?! What software do you recommend to solve it?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: What is the actual task that is to solve for this DE? It looks like terms thrown together so that none of the solution tricks will work and to make that obvious.

Comment: The representation as a differential form by $y'\to dy/dx$ yields
$$ 2 \text{dx}\  \left\{2 e^x \left(4 \left(x^2+y^3\right)+7 x \sin (x)\right)+e^{x-y}-e^{x+y}+2 e^y\right\}+\text{dy} e^x \left\{64 \cos (y)-7 \left(4 x+y^2\right)\right\}=0$$

To find an integrating factor, multiplying both coefficients such that 

$$d(f(x,y)\left(  a(x,y) dx + b(x,y) dy\right) =0, $$ yielding the condition

$$\partial_y ( f a)  = \partial_x (f b),$$

seems to be an impossible task.